# Android GalleryPicker or Gallery?

Tags: android

I downloaded Android 2.2 (proyo) source code and compiled it. 
I looked at the app folder and I found Gallery and Gallery3D.

I created an Android project from existing source code(Gallery) on Eclipse. It appears on Eclipse as GalleryPicker with errors. If I created an Android project from Gallerry3D then it doesn't complain.

My question is what is the difference between Gallery and GalleryPicker (Gallery3d and Gallery in Android source code).

Also, how do I get rid of errors on the GalleryPicker?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you please update your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow your question correctly Gallery3d is an application (loaded from your app drawer) for viewing images and Gallery (android.widgets.Gallery, I believe) is a widget which displays a filmstrip of images above a blow up of the selected image.